# Is there any other way for webOTP to autofill sms in react PWA without sms format in Android?

Tags: android, reactjs, format, progressive-web-apps, autofill

I work in a company that asked me to autofill OTP in our pwa react app. I am using web-otp api to do that. and I am successes fully done with it. but they want me to do that without sms format (@domain-name #codenumber) at the bottom of each sms.

Os: Android
Technology: React pwa(not react native)

as I researched I hit a dead end.

an am sure there is no other way than that in pwa in android os.

my question is, is there another way?